# collision not triggered when i touch object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have 1 First Person Controller as a player and created 1 cube as an enemy.

Enemy has rigidbody to assign gravity to it and it moving on 1 platform which is made from cube.

collision detect script is attached with enemy. **when enemy touches the player method triggered successfully. but when Player touch enemy method is not called.**

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

       Collider other=collision.collider;
       Debug.Log(string.Format("OnCollisionEnter tag={0}",other.tag));
         //                   

       if(other.gameObject.tag=="Player")
       {
         Debug.Log("Player1 Touched");
       }
}
```

Comment: Has the player attached a RigidBody too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

as I have used firstpersoncontroller i have to implement below method to find collision

```
 void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit collision)
        {
  Debug.Log(string.Format("object tag={0}",collision.collider.gameObject.tag));
    }
```

Thank you all for your help.
unity link that helped me.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html